# Single word for "a word that can have different interpretations"

Tags: single-word-requests

> The ***importance*** of a factor depends on how ***importance*** is defined.
>   The word ***importance*** has a fuzzy nature open to different
>   interpretations and the ***importance*** of a factor depends on how
>   ***importance*** is defined.
>
> In other words, ***importance*** is ...

How can I complete this sentence with one word?

**Edit**:

I prefer to use a neutral word without negative connotations, since I'm not against having different interpretations in this case. Rather, I mean depending on how *importance* is defined, we need a different method.

Comment: Q: *What is a single word for “a word that can have different interpretations”* ... A: "word".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**weasel word**

> noun
>
> a word used in order to avoid being clear or direct.
> — [Merriam-Webster's Learner's Dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/weasel%20word).

> noun
>
> a word used in order to evade or retreat from a direct or forthright statement or position
> *"Reorganization” is just a weasel word that the company is using to say that jobs are being eliminated*.
> — M-W

Comment: Thanks @K1eran Does weasel word have a negative meaning?

Comment: @MFR I can't think how it could be a compliment.

Comment: Thank you, Weasel word is a good option but I'm still open to other suggestions. I prefer to use a neutral word since I'm not against having different interpretations in this case. Rather, I mean depending on how importance is defined, we need a different method.

Comment: @MFR I think you should add a **edit** into original question to clarify you want neutral word without negative connotations.

Comment: Sure, I'll do shortly.  sorry for not being clear

Answer (score 3):

How about *ambiguous* or *vague*?

M-W:

> [*ambiguous*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ambiguous): able to be understood in more than one way : having
> more than one possible meaning; not expressed or understood clearly
>
> [*vague*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vague): not clear
> in meaning; stated in a way that is general and not specific

Your example:

> The importance of a factor depends on how importance is defined. The
> word importance has a fuzzy nature open to different interpretations
> and the importance of a factor depends on how importance is defined.
>
> In other words, importance is *ambiguous* or *vague*.

Other possibilities are *(too) general* and *non-specific*.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that the matter of interpreting the word in this case is **[subjective](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=subjective)**: it depends on your experience, understanding and feelings.

Comment: Please add reference so I can up vote your answer.

Comment: References/links seem to be expected. In any event, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[Equivocality:](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/equivocality) Allowing the possibility of several different meanings, as a word or phrase, especially with intent to deceive or misguide; susceptible of double interpretation; deliberately ambiguous.

[Amphiboly:](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/amphiboly) Ambiguity of speech, especially from uncertainty of the grammatical construction rather than of the meaning of the words.